# Which of the following answer choices is a factor of P(x)?

Tags: polynomials

2. A polynomial P(x) such that P(3/4) =0. Which of the following answer choices is a factor of P(x)?
   a.   4x-3
   b.  4x+3 
   c.   3x-4
   d.   3x+4

Thank you

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the factor theorem, $x - \frac{3}{4}$ is a factor of $P(x)$. This is the same as $4x - 3$ being a factor.